# Git installation RHEL Linux failing with "warning: zlib.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: git, zlib, rhel, failed-installation

I am installing git following the document.

But I am getting below error after running make command
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/git-install-configure/

```
 [root@liaan17 git-1.8.2.3]# make
CC credential-store.o
```

In file included from credential-store.c:1:

cache.h:19:18: warning: zlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from credential-store.c:1:

cache.h:21: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘z_stream’

Comment: Try `sudo yum install zlib-devel` then run make again.

Comment: Thanks for looking.That didn't work.

Comment: No package zlib-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: If you do a `yum search zlib`, what do you get?

Comment: Error Message:
        Please run rhn_register as root on this client
Error Class Code: 9
Error Class Info: Invalid System Credentials.
Explanation:
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com.
     If you choose to submit the bug report, please be sure to include
     details of what you were trying to do when this error occurred and
     details on how to reproduce this problem.
Setting up Install Process
No package zlib-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Please find the above error

Comment: Got it, thanks. If you search for zlib using yum, do you see any packages?

Comment: [root@liaan17 git-1.8.2.3]# yum search zlib
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.Error Message:
        Please run rhn_register as root on this client
Error Class Code: 9
Error Class Info: Invalid System Credentials.
Explanation:
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com

Comment: N/S Matched: zlib 
perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 : Low-Level Interface to zlib compression library
perl-Compress-Zlib.x86_64 : A module providing Perl interfaces to the zlib compression library
perl-IO-Compress-Zlib.noarch : Perl interface to zlib
perl-IO-Zlib.x86_64 : Perl IO:: style interface to Compress::Zlib
perl-POE-Filter-Zlib.noarch : POE filter wrapped around Compress::Zlib
zlib.x86_64 : The zlib compression and decompression library
perl-IO-Compress-Zlib.x86_64 : Perl interface to allow reading and writing of gzip and zip data

Comment: above is the output of yum search zlib in splitted into two comments.

Comment: Odd - not sure why it's not there, but given that's the case you'll probably need to download and install the correct rpm for your distro from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=zlib-devel - hope that gets it working for you.

Comment: Solved it by wget http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz and installed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by wget zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz and installed the same

Answer (score 4):

Centos 7:

```
yum install zlib-devel.x86_64
```